# How do I change the UEFI Boot Order from within Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi, bcdedit

I have multiple Operating systems installed, each with their respective EFI file in the ESP (EFI System Partition).

For example: I have Windows 10 at `\EFI\Boot\Microsoft\bootmgr.efi`, and I have WinPE at `\EFI\WinPE\Boot\bootx64.efi`

When I boot into my BIOS I can see the list of operating systems, but I would like to be able to give windows a command to change the order and then shutdown, effectively telling Windows to boot into a different operating system.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not documented anywhere by Microsoft. However I was able to look through the source code of [Grub2Win](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub2win/) to see how they accomplished switching order.

Aparrently there is a `bcdedit` object called `{fwbootmgr}` if you change the display order of that item, it will effectively change the Boot order within the UEFI.

`bcdedit /set {fwbootmgr} displayorder <ID_OF_NEW_OS> {bootmgr}`

You can get the id of the other UEFI entries by doing: `bcdedit /enum {fwbootmgr}` and looking at the boot entries under `displayorder`.

Comment: After the `bcdedit /enum {fwbootmgr}` I get a list of 5 ids. I have change the order of the ids as bcedit /displayorder {id2} {id1} {id3} ...

Comment: It is well documented (the earliest archived link is from 2017, but I'm pretty sure it was there much earlier) – [BCDEdit / displayorder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/bcdedit--displayorder).

Answer (score 0):

Use [`bcdedit /displayorder`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/devtest/bcdedit--displayorder):

```
bcdedit /displayorder {802d5e32-0784-11da-bd33-000476eba25f} {cbd971bf-b7b8-4885-951a-fa03044f5d71}
```

`bcdedit /enum` lists the ids present in the system.

Comment: Yes, but the ids showed here are invalid, as are different for each system. @Dylan question is better than this one

Comment: @KingMidas And what IDs would you expect? The ones from your system nobody is aware of? It's only an example from the official docs.